# search for CRM 2011-like Ui controls in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, user-interface, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I just got an analysis task for an alternative Web UI for our product. My boss likes CRM 2011, so he'd like to get something similar-looking or even the CRM controls themselves, if available. We unfortunately can't build on top of the CRM, as we have pretty sophisticated needs and a very old legacy codebase.

My question: given this screenshot [image]
how much is already available to Webdevelopers, given they target WebForms or MVC. 
It seems to use some "standard" UI methodologies in MS world (very Office/desktop-like), like the ribbon, which got "free for everyone" with WPF in .NET 4.5, so maybe that's true for the webcontrols, too? Couldn't find it with a quick search, though.

If that's a dead end, what about 3rd party vendors? Anyone giving you the opportunity to use ribbon and such very desktop-like webcontrols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telerik has some really nice controls for dotNet.  Here's the ribbon you are looking for: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/ribbonbar/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: ok, that seems nice, but I won't give uop my hope on the other controls just yet ;) Especially the sidebar.. accepted answer once I'm sure noone else shows up with a better answer.

Comment: Telerik actually has a side bar as well; however, it should be very easy to replicate the side bar without having to use a 3rd party control.  If you're looking to just lift some styling, sign-up for a free CRM 2011 trial and then use Developer Tools inside Internet Explorer (from IE, press F12 on the keyboard -> click the mouse pointer icon in the window that pops up -> select the button/area you want on the page -> Look at the CSS styling on the object and the HTML to build it)